# How to edit Source code for SharePoint Server?

Tags: sharepoint

I have SharePoint installed on my personal servers and I want to add some peace of codes in the main source code and these are customized code which I could not create using SharePoint editing options and they must be added into source code of SharePoint source file.
I also want to edit the header where it state SharePoint at the top and add some codes and I would like replace it with my own code which is HTML and JavaScript and it contains links to my websites and some logo and search box and I want it to be at the top of SharePoint in the header. I am unable to find which aspx , I have to modify to reflect my changes.

Comment: Replacing header content  from SharPoint  you need edit the MasterPage or write Javascript to replace/change content. To add content to the page, you may use content editor/ Script editor where you can place your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

[Change SharePoint logo](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818#ID0EABAAA=2013,_2016)

You could add custom code by customizing SharePoint Master Page.
[Steps To Create Custom Master Page In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-design-manager/)

Of course, you can also directly modify the relevant pages in SharePoint designer.
[SharePoint Designer 2013 Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491)
[SharePoint Designer Introduction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introducing-sharepoint-designer-66bf58fe-daeb-4fa6-ae84-fd600e0005c1)

Comment: I want to modify local aspx files , I don't want to use the designer because I have limit options.

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgdqA.png)

I want to edit above part, I don't know which Master page would change it.
I believe it only could be done by modifying the master page and I want to add some HTML like add search box and link to apps.

Comment: You could find your master page in design manager and SharePoint Designer.